# concatenate with null and no condition

Tags: excel, vba

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZurbE.png]

From the attached image in column DN, I am concatenating columns from DJ to DM.
But if the cell contains **null** value or **no** it shouldnt print in the concatenation.
can someone pls guide me in this by suggesting ideas how can i proceed further
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try `TEXTJOIN` and `IF` yet?

Comment: Can you include the VBA code you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to O365, and thus access to FILTER() and TEXJOIN(), then you can do this all in a fairly simple formula and not require VBA.  You'll end up with

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTER(DJ5:DM5,DJ5:DM5<>"no",""))
```

in DN5 and copy it down.  The FILTER takes care of the "no" values and the "true" in TEXTJOIN correctly ignores blank cells.

You can go further by using the BYROW or MAKEARRAY function to calculate the entire result in column DN all at once with a single formula in DN5.